# Order Producst by Features Relevance in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

How you doing?

I'm new here at Stack Overflow and I'd like to share with you about my situation hoping someone will help me with my problem. I'm programing in Python, practicing my poor skills in Machine Learning, but I'm facing a problem now where I don't know if ML could solve it or not.

Here's the thing:

I need to sort a bunch of products with multiples features by relevance. In this exemple I have 5 products with 7 features which is represented by 1 in case of have the feature, and by 0 if it doesn't have the feature.
[Table with sample products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3kO2.png)

In the real case I wanna print all of them sorted by relevance. I'd like to create weights for those features(I wanna set a relevance for each of them, for exemplo: Feature 7 is more relevante than Feature 6, and Feature 5 is more relevante than Feature 6 and so on but I don't want to exclude any feature) and do the ordering for me

I was searching about **Classification** or **Decision Tree** but I didn't find anything that could help me in this situation. I just need an advice about which technique I need to study to do this.

Thank you folks.

Comment: Suppose you don't care about whether the feature is missing or not you could use statistical tools such as Pearson's correlation coefficient to calculate the features' covariances. This would give you a good idea about which features are redundant

Comment: Hey @JosmyFaure! Thank you for your feedback! But in my case the features doesn't have any correlation because they're completly independent.  What I'm trying to say is that I need to order my products based in their features. For exemplo: I'll set the importance for each feature(from the most relevant to least one) and let the machine make the calculation and order all the products for me. The situation here is because a product can have more relevante features than other but I need to show all of them in order(from the best to the worst).

Comment: You may find this link useful https://machinelearningmastery.com/calculate-feature-importance-with-python/

Comment: I'll study about it. Thank you for you help @JosmyFaure!!!!